# <data> is a unresolvable tag in XML

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to follow tutorials on data binding and most of them recommend using a data tag in my XML files.

However, when I try to add them, it shows up red with no way to fix it.

Comment: Did you enable data binding in your build.gradle? https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/start#build_environment

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to encase my xml in a <layer